# Android SDK, set text in custom dialog layout

Tags: android-layout, android-activity

So, i need to change the dialogs textView in a custom layout, i have tried some things but they all seem to fail. It maybe keeps crashing because findViewById is not coded right...

```
saveMod.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            Dialog dl = new Dialog(getBaseContext());


            TextView textLoad = (TextView) dl.findViewById(R.id.textViewBuild);
            textLoad.setText("Random Text");

            dl.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
            dl.setCancelable(false);
            dl.setContentView(R.layout.modactivity_building);
            dl.show();

        }
    });
```

When i click the button my app crashes..

and heres the log cat

```
12-22 18:20:32.063: E/AndroidRuntime(30116): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
12-22 18:20:32.063: E/AndroidRuntime(30116): Process: com.Hashimo.mcpeedit, PID: 30116
12-22 18:20:32.063: E/AndroidRuntime(30116): java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.TextView.setText(java.lang.CharSequence)' on a null object reference
12-22 18:20:32.063: E/AndroidRuntime(30116):    at com.Hashimo.mcpeedit.MODMainActivity$2.onClick(MODMainActivity.java:83)
12-22 18:20:32.063: E/AndroidRuntime(30116):    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4756)
12-22 18:20:32.063: E/AndroidRuntime(30116):    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:19749)
12-22 18:20:32.063: E/AndroidRuntime(30116):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
12-22 18:20:32.063: E/AndroidRuntime(30116):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
12-22 18:20:32.063: E/AndroidRuntime(30116):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
12-22 18:20:32.063: E/AndroidRuntime(30116):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221)
12-22 18:20:32.063: E/AndroidRuntime(30116):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
12-22 18:20:32.063: E/AndroidRuntime(30116):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
12-22 18:20:32.063: E/AndroidRuntime(30116):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
12-22 18:20:32.063: E/AndroidRuntime(30116):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
```

Comment: you are not getting the object of Textview into textLoad , are you using this in a fragment or an activity? rather than getting the dialog inside the onclick ,try initializing it in onCreate itself,then use that view to get the textview id.

Answer (score 1):

Put this line

```
dl.setContentView(R.layout.modactivity_building);
```

below this line

```
Dialog dl = new Dialog(getBaseContext());
```